# Handling timeout of UDP datagram socket in Java

Tags: java, datagram

I need to enable and disable the timeout of a UDP datagram socket in Java.

It is possible to set its timeout using `sendTokenSock.setSoTimeout(10000);`.

But if I need to disable its timeout and keep it receiving infinitely in another state in the program, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that `sendTokenSock` is a [`java.net.DatagramSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html): `sendTokenSock.setSoTimeout(0);` will set an infinite timeout as [`setSoTimeout` documentation for Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) explains:

> The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: Even the [__DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout(int)__](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-), gives the same information